# Accessing an entry in an array within Tikz within which was passed to a macro as argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to label a path with is defined by a list of coordinates (pairs of x- and y-values and no "real" tikz coordinate type). in a second list I store the labels for the edges. Both lists are input arguments to a macro. The idea is during drawing the path using a `foreach` loop over the first list, accessing the labels of the second list with the index I got from `count`. But instead of getting the labels I get the whole second list printed at each point.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}

\newcommand{\drawPoints}[2]{
    \foreach \x [count=\xi from 2,remember=\x as \lastx] in #1 {
        \ifnum\xi>2
            \draw \lastx -- \x node[midway] {#2[\xi]};
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawPoints{{(0,0),(1,2),(3,4),(5,1),(7,0)}}{{l1,l2,l3,l4,l5}}%T1
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to get TeX to expands `#2[\xi]` so that I get the right label at the right place?

One could think of combining both lists into one in the way of "point/label" but that's not the point of the question. I'm interested into figuring out how to access the second list by an index.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates get parsed, node contents don't, so you need to parse yourself. And you need wrap the texts in `"`. Since you decided to start counting from `2`, I had to subtract 2 in order to avoid going out of bounds; if you had started from 0 this would not be necessary. (And notice that using `\xi`, which stands for a Greek letter, as the loop variable may not be optimal, but I left it in. Finally, `10pt` is close to `3.14mm`, but does not precisely coincide. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}

\newcommand{\drawPoints}[2]{
    \foreach \x [count=\xi from 2,remember=\x as \lastx] in #1 {
        \ifnum\xi>2
            \draw \lastx -- \x node[midway] {\pgfmathsetmacro{\pft}{#2[\xi-2]}\pft};
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawPoints{{(0,0),(1,2),(3,4),(5,1),(7,0)}}{{"l1","l2","l3","l4","l5"}}%T1
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also draw the thing as one path, which looks better when one zooms in.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}

\newcommand{\drawPoints}[2]{\draw foreach  \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in #1 {\ifnum\Y>0 -- 
node[midway]{\pgfmathparse{#2[\Y]}\pgfmathresult} \fi \X} ;}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawPoints{{(0,0),(1,2),(3,4),(5,1),(7,0)}}{{"l1","l2","l3","l4","l5"}}%T1
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```